# Problem with macbook pro default iSight(built-in iSight)

Tags: macos, skype, isight

I have many trouble with my iSight, in skype in show green video instead of my video, in "image capture" iSight was not recogonized , just it was recognized in "photo Booth".

When I wanted to switch to [ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/). I downloaded and installed it without any problems, but when I want to run it I get an error. (some one tell me this error was because of your built-in iSight)

I'm on OS X 10.6.4.

Here is half of the error log (SU text limitation):

```
Process:         JavaApplicationStub [12990]
Path:            /Applications/ooVoo.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.ooVoo
Version:         ??? (2.2.0.89)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [160]

PlugIn Path:       /Applications/ooVoo.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libos.jnilib
PlugIn Identifier: libos.jnilib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (???)

Date/Time:       2010-09-11 02:09:20.997 +0430
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          287818 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  22 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      06CF1D49-5A90-414A-906E-B654595E9640

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:

Java information:
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=0000000093751bf0

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01-279 mixed mode macosx-x86)

Current thread (0000000002800c00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=-1332719616, stack(00000000b0105000,00000000b0905000)]
Stack: [00000000b0105000,00000000b0905000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  os.video.OSVideoUtils.createDevicesList()V+0
j  os.video.OSVideoUtils.<init>()V+15
j  os.video.OSVideoUtils.getVideoUtils()Los/video/OSVideoUtils;+10
j  arel.b2.f()V+25
j  arel.SeeUApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+550
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run()V+76
j  apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain()V+1
j  apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JJZ)V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  000000000208d000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=-1314717696, stack(00000000b1930000,00000000b1a30000)]
  0000000002078400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=-1315774464, stack(00000000b182e000,00000000b192e000)]
  0000000002064000 JavaThread "setCountersThread" [_thread_blocked, id=-1317924864, stack(00000000b1621000,00000000b1721000)]
  0000000002065000 JavaThread "Registry update task" [_thread_blocked, id=-1316831232, stack(00000000b172c000,00000000b182c000)]
  0000000002063800 JavaThread "AWT-AppKit" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=-1605085952, stack(00000000bf800000,00000000c0000000)]
  000000000205e800 JavaThread "ooVoo application host iteraction task" [_thread_blocked, id=-1318981632, stack(00000000b151f000,00000000b161f000)]
  00000000028a1400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1321095168, stack(00000000b131b000,00000000b141b000)]
  000000000201a000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1322151936, stack(00000000b1219000,00000000b1319000)]
  0000000002000800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1323208704, stack(00000000b1117000,00000000b1217000)]
  0000000002018c00 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (CMS)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1324265472, stack(00000000b1015000,00000000b1115000)]
  000000000289a400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1325322240, stack(00000000b0f13000,00000000b1013000)]
  0000000002899400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=-1326379008, stack(00000000b0e11000,00000000b0f11000)]
=>0000000002800c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=-1332719616, stack(00000000b0105000,00000000b0905000)]
Other Threads:
  0000000002897c00 VMThread [stack: 00000000b0d0f000,00000000b0e0f000] [id=-1327435776]
  00000000028a2800 WatcherThread [stack: 00000000b141d000,00000000b151d000] [id=-1320038400]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 par new generation   total 14784K, used 8527K [0000000005010000, 0000000006010000, 0000000007010000)
  eden space 13184K,  64% used [0000000005010000, 0000000005863cb8, 0000000005cf0000)
  from space 1600K,   0% used [0000000005cf0000, 0000000005cf0000, 0000000005e80000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0000000005e80000, 0000000005e80000, 0000000006010000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 245760K, used 0K [0000000007010000, 0000000016010000, 0000000025010000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 12288K, used 8203K [0000000025010000, 0000000025c10000, 0000000029010000)

Virtual Machine Arguments:
JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Resources/LauncherSupport.jar -Xms256m -Xmx512m 
Java Command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic
Physical Memory: Page Size = 4k, Total = 3840M, Free = 108M


Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a260fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a26867 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93785faf __CFRunLoopRun + 2079
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93785094 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93784ec1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95587f9c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95587d51 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 354
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95587bd6 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 81
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x91cbfa89 _DPSNextEvent + 847
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x91cbf2ca -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 156
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x91c8155b -[NSApplication run] + 821
11  libawt.jnilib                   0x2a75021c +[AWTStarter startAWT:] + 1768
12  libawt.jnilib                   0x2a70b28b -[CPerformer perform] + 243
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x9754cea4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 705
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x937880fb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1563
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93785bbf __CFRunLoopRun + 1071
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93785094 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93784ec1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
18  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x0000728a startupJava(LauncherArgsStruct*) + 342
19  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x000065cb launchJavaApplication + 1355
20  JavaApplicationStub             0x00001e8c 0x1000 + 3724
21  JavaApplicationStub             0x00001d0e 0x1000 + 3342
22  JavaApplicationStub             0x00001c35 0x1000 + 3125

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4b9d2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4bf68 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4bb86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4c942 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4d05c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4c519 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4c2be _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4bd41 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a4bb86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93751bf0 CFStringGetLength + 80
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9376615f CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 47
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93766125 CFStringCompareWithOptions + 53
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x937660e0 CFStringCompare + 64
4   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x4110db44 CoreBundleyes::IsMainMember() const + 48
5   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x4110b1cc QVDigBaseClass::ClassFactory(ComponentInstanceRecord*) + 50
6   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x4110d17b QVDIG_DATA_Open + 23
7   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x9137f56c CallComponentFunctionCommonWithStorage(char**, ComponentParameters*, long (*)(), unsigned long) + 54
8   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x4110c8a5 QVDIG_DATA_ComponentDispatch + 130
9   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377ce5 CallComponentDispatch + 29
10  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377cc6 CallComponentOpen + 43
11  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91375f94 OpenAComponent + 433
12  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x989b81df _SGVideoSetVideoDigitizerComponent + 761
13  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x9137f56c CallComponentFunctionCommonWithStorage(char**, ComponentParameters*, long (*)(), unsigned long) + 54
14  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x989af96e _SGVideoComponentDispatch + 129
15  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377ce5 CallComponentDispatch + 29
16  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x98aede92 SGSetVideoDigitizerComponent + 43
17  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x989af6f7 _SGVideoInitChannel + 117
18  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x9137f56c CallComponentFunctionCommonWithStorage(char**, ComponentParameters*, long (*)(), unsigned long) + 54
19  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x989af96e _SGVideoComponentDispatch + 129
20  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377ce5 CallComponentDispatch + 29
21  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x98aee3c7 SGInitChannel + 43
22  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x989a01fb _SGNewChannelFromComponent + 97
23  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x9137f56c CallComponentFunctionCommonWithStorage(char**, ComponentParameters*, long (*)(), unsigned long) + 54
24  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x9899ca87 _SGComponentDispatch + 129
25  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377ce5 CallComponentDispatch + 29
26  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x98aef223 SGNewChannelFromComponent + 49
27  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x9899d11b _SGNewChannel + 117
28  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x9137f56c CallComponentFunctionCommonWithStorage(char**, ComponentParameters*, long (*)(), unsigned long) + 54
29  ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x9899ca87 _SGComponentDispatch + 129
30  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x91377ce5 CallComponentDispatch + 29
31  com.apple.QuickTime             0x9933a13a SGNewChannel + 49
32  libos.jnilib                    0x3f46688f -[SGUtils makeSGDeviceListForVideoChannel] + 328
33  libos.jnilib                    0x3f466c6c Java_os_video_OSVideoUtils_createDevicesList + 331
34  ???                             0x0300b959 0 + 50379097
35  ???                             0x03003db1 0 + 50347441
36  ???                             0x03003db1 0 + 50347441
37  ???                             0x03003f17 0 + 50347799
38  ???                             0x03003db1 0 + 50347441
39  ???                             0x030012d3 0 + 50336467
40  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a3500 JVM_Lseek + 139952
41  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a32a6 JVM_Lseek + 139350
42  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a3276 JVM_Lseek + 139302
43  libjvm.dylib                    0x018c6008 JVM_NewInstanceFromConstructor + 3896
44  libjvm.dylib                    0x018c7bfe JVM_InvokeMethod + 1342
45  libjvm.dylib                    0x018c78b2 JVM_InvokeMethod + 498
46  libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x0006772f JVM_InvokeMethod + 79
47  libjava.jnilib                  0x000a6132 Java_sun_reflect_NativeMethodAccessorImpl_invoke0 + 38
48  ???                             0x0300b959 0 + 50379097
49  ???                             0x03003f17 0 + 50347799
50  ???                             0x03003f17 0 + 50347799
51  ???                             0x030043f3 0 + 50349043
52  ???                             0x03003f17 0 + 50347799
53  ???                             0x03003db1 0 + 50347441
54  ???                             0x03003db1 0 + 50347441
55  ???                             0x030012d3 0 + 50336467
56  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a3500 JVM_Lseek + 139952
57  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a32a6 JVM_Lseek + 139350
58  libjvm.dylib                    0x018a3276 JVM_Lseek + 139302
59  libjvm.dylib                    0x018d4181 JVM_FindLoadedClass + 3553
60  libjvm.dylib                    0x0190c162 JVM_Socket + 5170
61  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x00008b22 JNIEnv_::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...) + 44
62  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x000089f2 CallAppLauncherMain(JNIEnv_*, __CFDictionary const*, __CFArray const*) + 286
63  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x000081ed startJavaApplication + 3745
64  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x0000734a runJava(LauncherArgsStruct*) + 78
65  ...ple.JavaApplicationLauncher  0x000072f4 java_main_stub(void*) + 22
66  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a5381d _pthread_start + 345
67  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a536a2 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:  Java: Exception Handler Thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a260fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a26867 mach_msg + 68
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a91e18 mach_msg_server + 520
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x01810e75 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 62437
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x01810e1a JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 62346
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f38b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55547
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a5381d _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a536a2 thread_start + 34

Thread 5:  Java: Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a260fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a26867 mach_msg + 68
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180ff73 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 58595
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180fdfb JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 58219
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f978 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57064
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f5d8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56136
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x01825d71 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x01825caa jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f38b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55547
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a5381d _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a536a2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:  Java: Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a260fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a26867 mach_msg + 68
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180ff73 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 58595
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180fdfb JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 58219
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f978 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57064
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f5d8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56136
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x01825d71 jio_vsnprintf + 321
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x01825caa jio_vsnprintf + 122
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f38b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55547
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a5381d _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a536a2 thread_start + 34

Thread 7:  Java: Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a260fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a26867 mach_msg + 68
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x01810087 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 58871
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0182d110 jio_vsnprintf + 29920
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180fa07 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 57207
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f5d8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 56136
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x018e683c JVM_Available + 29228
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0182cef2 jio_vsnprintf + 29378
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x0180f38b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 55547
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a5381d _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x93a536a2 thread_start + 34


Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xa05108cc  ebx: 0x93751bb1  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000007
  edi: 0xb09036c4  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xb0903168  esp: 0xb0903150
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010283  eip: 0x93751bf0   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000000


Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.53 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.47f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.91.27)
Bluetooth: Version 2.3.7f1, 2 service, 12 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Network Service: Parallels Shared Networking Adapter, Ethernet, en2
Network Service: Parallels Host-Only Networking Adapter, Ethernet, en3
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK2555GSXF, 232.89 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0x26500000
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8213, 0x06110000
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0236, 0x04600000
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x04500000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if your camera is recognized by the system by rebooting your machine and holding down the "D" key while it's starting up. This will launch the hardware diagnostics. A better diagnostic is available if you go to an Apple Store.

Comment: I live in the city that have no Apple store :(

Comment: If the basic diagnostics don't give enough information about the iSight camera, you can try searching for an Apple Authorized Service Provider to run the diagnostics.

Comment: and also holding down D " D : Forces the first internal hard drive to be the startup disk." what's the point of this? you sure about "D" or must hold other key(s)?

Comment: To run the hardware diagnostics you hold the 'D' key while booting from the original startup CD for your machine.

Comment: I miss my original CD!!! :(

Comment: For Intel Macs shipping with OS X 10.5.4 or less, the diagnostics are located on the CD so you hold D while the CD is in the machine. If it shipped with Mac OS X 10.5.5 or greater, it is on the machine itself(just hold down D). KB-HT1509 http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509

Comment: @Madison I have Mac OS X 10.6.4 but when I hold "D" during boot nothing happened.

Comment: Then your machine must have shipped with 10.5.4 or less. If you don't have your original CD, you can have Apple send you a replacement by contacting Apple Support.

Answer (score 0):

**1st**:  Be sure you've got the most recent updates & you've fixed permissions (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452?viewlocale=en_US) .
Next, I would re-install quicktime & skype and also reset the SMC ( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US )

**2nd**:  I still had this issue with my MBP 10.6 & (after doing the thing in item #1 above) found that the ~/library/preferences/com.apple.digihub.plist file had some strange reference to application "110" accessing the DV (camera).  It said:

```
<key>com.apple.digihub.dvcamera.IIDC.irisopened</key>
<dict>
<key>action</key>
<integer>110</integer>
</dict>
```

Yet, my other Macs did not have this reference in the com.apple.digihub.plist file, so I removed it (be sure to save a back up copy of this file) and restarted in safe mode (http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=107393) and then when I rebooted again, it worked.

Good luck.

Comment: I try repair permission but for some library "javaVM" can't repair permission. I don'y have "com.apple.digihub.plist" in my prefpane library and because of rEFIt I can't boot on safe mode. I just do some part of your instruction but still have my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the file "com.apple.digihub.plist"? (you may be looking in the wrong preferences folder)  Try going to terminal and typing   mdfind com.apple.digihub.plist  to see if it finds it.

Comment: I find in with terminal "mdfind" command and also  can see it in finder.

Comment: I delete the file and boot in "safe mode" after restart in normal mode I still have this problem.